# Rhodes or Sinatra for iphone development?

Tags: iphone, ruby, sinatra, rhodes

i wanted to develop an iphone app in Ruby, so i was confused to go for which framework.. Rhodes or Sinatra.. 
My app has to integrate google maps, GPS etc.. 
Please suggest me :)

Comment: Are you going to release this app on the iPhone App Store?  Or is this actually a web app (in which case it doesn't matter if it's an iPhone or what).

Comment: it has to be installed on iphone

Comment: Sinatra is framework for writing web applications, so your last comment basically answered the question.

Comment: i was asking based on this
 http://devver.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/building-a-iphone-web-app-in-under-50-lines-with-sinatra-and-iui/

Answer (score 2):

iPhones run on iOS.  iOS will only run compiled Objective C.  If you do decide to code in something other than Objective C, you will have to convert it to Objective C before it will run on an iPhone.

Short version: use Objective C.  You'll need an Apple computer that uses an Intel processor.  You'll need the XCode software.

Rhodes is an example of "convert it to Objective C" after writing in another language.

Either way, you'll need an Apple computer with XCode and an Apple iOS Developer license ($99/year) in order to publish and install your app.